# juju bootstrap command finished but deployment failed

Tags: server, juju, maas, cloud

I have run juju -v --debug bootstrap -e auits and the last thing juju returns is

```
Logging to /var/log/cloud-init-output.log on remote host
Running apt-get update
Running apt-get upgrade
Installing package: git
Installing package: curl
Installing package: cpu-checker
Installing package: bridge-utils
Installing package: rsyslog-gnutls
Fetching tools: curl -sSfw 'tools from %{url_effective} downloaded: HTTP %{http_code}; time %{time_total}s; size %{size_download} bytes; speed %{speed_download} bytes/s ' --retry 10 -o $bin/tools.tar.gz 'https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/releases/juju-1.20.13-trusty-amd64.tgz'
Bootstrapping Juju machine agent
Starting Juju machine agent (jujud-machine-0)
2014-12-08 13:34:37 INFO juju.cmd supercommand.go:329 command finished
```

But the maas deployment fails and leaves the machine in a "Failed deployment" state.  It looks like the bootstrap worked, why the failed deployment?  Juju status says it is bootstrapped.

Full pastbin of log is at http://pastebin.com/3LDxnQyy

Comment: Would you accept you own answer as that what worked for you. It will others with same issue find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with the DNS forwarder on my MaaS server which was probably the cause of this. An upgrade to an updated MaaS pointed out the problem to me.  After fixing it machines seem to be deploying better.

Comment: could you elaborate on how you fixed it?